# Copying an Excel file and modifying the date to the next day (and looping this for multiple days)

Tags: excel, powershell, automation

I am having difficulty implementing this in powershell.
So I have a file called "FileName 12.14.2022.xlsx" which is in MM.DD.YYYY format in the filename.

I want to create a loop such that it will copy this file and create multiple copies of this file for future days. e.g. creating files with the filenames:

- FileName 12.14.2022.xlsx
- FileName 12.15.2022.xlsx
- FileName 12.16.2022.xlsx
- FileName 12.17.2022.xlsx

And I can set the loop counter to go as far forward as I want.
Any ideas how I can do this using powershell?

I tried to extract the day month and year and adding an extra day to it, but kept throwing an error.

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with, It's not the best but it does the job(Hopefully)

```
$Path = "Enter path here"
$File = "FileName 12.14.2022.xlsx"

#Removes all of the stuff from the file name in a very dirty way
$Date = $File.Split("FileName" + " " + ".xlsx") | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }
$DateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact("$($Date[0]) $($Date[1]) $($Date[2])", "M d yyyy", $null)

#Will ask how many times you want it to loops
#The $e variable is there to it will add days to the date
$i = Read-Host "Times to loop: "
$e = 1

#The loop that will make it all happen
1..$i  | % { 
    
    $AddingDate = $($([datetime]::ParseExact("$($Date[0]) $($Date[1]) $($Date[2])", "M d yyyy", $null)).AddDays($e)).ToString("MM.dd.yyyy")
    $NewFileName = "FileName $AddingDate.xlsx"
    Copy-Item "$Path$File" -Destination "$Path$NewFileName"
    $e = $e + 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use a loop incrementing the date taken from the original sourcefile like below:

```
# get the FileInfo object from the original source file
$sourceFile = Get-Item -Path 'X:\ThePathTo\FileName 12.14.2022.xlsx'
# extract the date from the source filename (as string)
$sourceDate = ($sourceFile.BaseName -split '\s+')[-1]
# extract the filename prefix (in demo "FileName")
$sourcePrefix = ($sourceFile.BaseName -replace "${sourceDate}$").Trim()

# convert the $sourceDate string into a real DateTime object
$startDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($sourceDate, 'MM\.dd\.yyyy', $null)
# set the end date by adding X days to the original start date (for demo three weeks)
$endDate   = $startDate.AddDays(21)

# next, in a loop copy the file
while ($startDate -le $endDate) {
    $startDate = $startDate.AddDays(1)  # increment to next day
    # construct the new file name
    $newName   = '{0} {1:MM.dd.yyyy}{2}' -f $sourcePrefix, $startDate, $sourceFile.Extension
    $newFile   = Join-Path -Path $sourceFile.DirectoryName -ChildPath $newName
    $sourceFile | Copy-Item -Destination $newFile -WhatIf
}
```

P.S. I have added switch `-WhatIf` to the copy-item line so you can first see in the console what *would* happen. If you are satisfied this is correct, remove that `-WhatIf` switch and run the code again